# how to use union in doctrine query symfony 1.4?

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, union

I want to have query like this in mysql:

**select a.x, a.y, a.foo, sum(a.bar) as bar_sum from mytable a groupby a.x union select a.x, a.y, a.bar, sum(a.foo) as foo_sum from mytable a groupby a.y**

this format is true? and how I can convert it to doctrine query in symfony?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that UNION is not supported using [DQL (doctrine query language)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/hu/dql-doctrine-query-language). But it looks like someone was able to get around the issue, using a nasty [heredoc](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/87860/).

Or, you could just add a custom method in an object peer class and write the query in native sql.

-- Edit --

Use the following as an example (untested):

```
// Assuming you have the default doctrine setup, where non-object classes are
//  appended with Table (your object being Foo)
class FooTable
{
    public static function getFooBarUnion()
    {
        $sql = "select a.x, a.y, a.foo, sum(a.bar) as bar_sum from mytable a groupby a.x union select a.x, a.y, a.bar, sum(a.foo) as foo_sum from mytable a groupby a.y";

        $results = Doctrine_Query::create()->query($sql);

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your link, and about adding custom method, I dont know how it works, can you give me an example please?

Comment: Interesting, I'll update post and change it to `Doctrine_Query::create()->query($sql)`. Thanks.